# the passed param by resttemplate.exchange was not decoded in service side automatically

Tags: spring-boot, decode, resttemplate

Below is my REST API code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" })
      @ApiOperation(value = "get data by key.", notes = "return json string value.")
      public JsonObjectResponse<String> get(
          @ApiParam(required = true, name = "regionName", value = "region name") @RequestParam("regionName") String regionName,
          @ApiParam(required = true, name = "key", value = "region key,Default is uuid") @RequestParam("key") String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
      {
        JsonObjectResponse<String> jr = new JsonObjectResponse<String>();
        //key = decodeJsonString(key);  // added for junit
        String val = adfService.onPath(regionName).get(key);
        jr.setState(StateCode.SUCCESS);
        jr.setData(JsonObject.create().append(key,val).toJson());

        return jr;
      }
```

I'm trying to pass parameters:

```
regionName=/fusion/table1&key={"fusionTbl1DetailNo":"fusionNo001","pk":"PK0001"}
```

1. If I call it via swagger-ui, it calls like this:

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/service/basic/get?regionName=%2Ffusion%2Ftable1&key=%7B%22fusionTbl1DetailNo%22%3A%22fusionNo001%22%2C%22pk%22%3A%22PK0001%22%7D&token=8652493a-4147-43f4-af3a-bcb117fb7d42`
   ```

   It encoded the parameters and these parameters also can be decoded automatically in server side correctly.
2. When I want to add testcase for this API, I use restTemplate.exchange method, code as below:

   ```
   UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);
   for (Entry<String, String> entry : queryParamMap.entrySet()) {
       builder.queryParam(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   }
   if (uriParamMap != null) {

       url = builder.buildAndExpand(uriParamMap).toUriString();
   } else {
       url = builder.toUriString();
   }
   if (StringUtils.isEmpty(requestBody)) {
       if (bodyParamMap != null) {
           requestBody = parseMapToParams(bodyParamMap);
       } else {
           requestBody = "";
       }
   }
   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "json", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
   headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
   // headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
   // headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
   // headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
   headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
   // headers.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
   headers.set("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
   headers.set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
   headers.add("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");
   headers.add("User-Agent",
           "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");

   headers.add(TestBase.TOKEN_HEADER, TestBase.getTokenId());
   HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
   restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
   ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, request, String.class);
   localresponse.set(response);
   System.out.println("response:" + response);
   return response;
   ```

I used `UriComponentsBuilder` to append the parameters, it will format the url to

```
http://localhost:8080/service/basic/get?regionName=/fusion/table1&key=%7B%22fusionTbl1DetailNo%22:%22fusionNo001%22,%22pk%22:%22PK0001%22%7D
```

for method `exchange`. However, when the server side received the call, it did not decode the param `key`, it's value still was:

```
%7B%22fusionTbl1DetailNo%22:%22fusionNo001%22,%22pk%22:%22PK0001%22%7D
```

Why is that? I compared the header settings from the swagger calling, added additional settings, no effect :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like the following:

```
ResponseEntity<String> res = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/service/basic/get?regionName={arg1}&key={arg2}", HttpMethod.POST, null, String.class,"/fusion/table1", "{\"fusionTbl1DetailNo\":\"fusionNo001\",\"pk\":\"PK0001\"}");
```

`arg1` and `arg2` will be replaced by

`"/fusion/table1"` and `"{\"fusionTbl1DetailNo\":\"fusionNo001\",\"pk\":\"PK0001\"}"`

I send `null` in `requestEntity` as no request body and request parameters is in uriVariables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `toUriString()` use, `UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url).queryParam("name","John Doe").build().toString();`

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Documentation on RestTemplate reads:

> For each HTTP method there are three variants: two accept a URI
>   template string and URI variables (array or map) while a third accepts
>   a URI. Note that for URI templates it is assumed encoding is
>   necessary, e.g. restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.com/hotel
>   list") becomes "http://example.com/hotel%20list". This also means if
>   the URI template or URI variables are already encoded, double encoding
>   will occur,

It looks like you are using a RestTemplate exchange method that takes a URI template string and you should therefore NOT encode the url-string.

The url-string is first encoded on

```
builder.toUriString()
```

And then again on the exchange-call. So the problem seems to be double encoding on the client side, not lack of decoding on the server side